# Multiple rows join

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-join-rows

Please help me with next problem.
I have next table:

```
|  Name  |  Size  |  DateTime    |
|--------|--------|--------------| 
| Adi    |  120   |  2017-01-26  |
|--------|--------|--------------|
| Mark   | 225    | 2017-01-11   |
|--------|--------|--------------|
| Adi    | 150    | 2017-01-28   |
|--------|--------|--------------|
| Adi    | 115    | 2017-02-01   |
|--------|--------|--------------|
| Adi    | 170    | 2017-02-05   |
|--------|--------|--------------|
```

I need to put one more column with all registrations of each name(if exist), ordereb by DateTime column like this:

```
| Name   | Size1 | Size2 | Size3 | 
|--------|-------|-------|-------| 
| Adi    | 120   | 150   | 115   | 
|--------|-------|-------|-------|
```

I have tried with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table.Name, table.Size
FROM database.table AS table
JOIN database.table AS table1
ON table.Name = table.Name
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Adding a column in the query isn't enough? Are you missing rows (use LEFT JOIN).

Comment: I need to put one more column with all registrations of each name(if exist), ordereb by DateTime column

Answer (score 1):

Group by the column you want to be unique. Aggregate functions like `min()` apply to each unique group and not the whole result set

```
select name, 
       min(size) as size1, 
       max(size) as size2
from your_table
group by name
having min(size) <> max(size)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need to order by date. And is possible to have 5 or 15 entry on same name but different dates

Comment: Please update your question. Add your real requirements